# WeifenLuo DockContent minimum size not working

Tags: c#, winforms

Hey i got a Form inheriting `DockContent` from WeifenLuo.

```
public partial class ImportForm : DockContent
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ImportForm" /> class.
    /// Constructor for non modal import control window
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="guiLogic">The GUI logic.</param>
    public ImportForm(GuiLogic guiLogic)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.MinimumSize = new Size(400, 400);
    }
}
```

The problem is when I run the program I can drag my ImportForm as small as i want in width and height. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The feature of Windows forms that you know and love - whereby the window won't let you resize it beyond certain limits - has not been implemented in the WeifenLuo DockPanelSuite. If you want this functionality you will have to implement it yourself by modifying the [source code](https://www.openhub.net/p/dockpanelsuite).

If this sounds like too much work, perhaps just handling the resize event will help you achieve your objectives. Here's an example:

```
public partial class ImportForm : DockContent
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ImportForm" /> class.
    /// Constructor for non modal import control window
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="guiLogic">The GUI logic.</param>
    public ImportForm(GuiLogic guiLogic)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.MinimumSize = new Size(400, 400);
        this.Resize += new EventHandler(ResizeEvent);
    }

    // If the content won't display nicely, hide it
    private void ResizeEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Visible = this.Width > this.MinimumSize.Width && this.Height > this.MinimumSize.Height;
    }

}
```

Hope this helps.